# Should the LGBT tag just be sexuality?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There is currently  a tag [lgbt](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt) that seems to be put on questions asking about the sexual preference of characters.  However, since LGBT does not cover the "full spectrum" of sexuality, should we just create a [sexuality](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality)  tag to cover all questions that relate to the subject?

Comment: I fully support using an overarching term rather than the ever-growing set of letters. Last I checked, they were trying to cram another one into QUILTBAG...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like this idea. I've retagged all [lgbt](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt) questions as [sexuality](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality) for now. As you note, the [lgbt](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lgbt) tag is somewhat imprecise. Since the acronym lgbt refers to a group of people, it's not clear if the tag refers to literature written by lgbt authors, lgbt characters, etc.

In the future, we might want to think about creating a "queer-theory" tag. (Assuming we get good questions about queer theory.) We might also want to potentially think about creating a "queer-subtext" tag.

Comment: Yes, better tag wiki and usage guidance might help as well.

Comment: I've also added a tag synonym from [lgbt] to [sexuality].

Answer (score 8):

Sure.

This way we avoid all the arguments about 'q' and the tag covers a larger number of questions. Also, anyone who's an expert in those questions will probably also be knowledgeable about the other questions that would be covered by this proposed tag.

Comment: If this gains community consensus, the tag is already created.